# Trouble with return in loop plotting real time data using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have problem when use value from list in this code. Return syntax breaks the loop and I can use all the data from the list.
This is my code:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    value1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for i in range(0,len(value1)):
        data = [time() * 1000, value1[i]]
        response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
        response.content_type = 'application/json'
        return response
```

Thanks

Comment: The function will execute only the first iteration of the loop and return the response. What would you like to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring an empty list, and append the results to the list in the for-loop before returning it, like this:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    value1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    response_arr = []
    for i in range(0,len(value1)):
        data = [time() * 1000, value1[i]]
        response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
        response.content_type = 'application/json'
        response_arr.append(response)

    return response_arr
```

Comment: In this way you will have the `response` variable overwritten at each iteration of the loop, hence you will return only the last assignment.

Comment: Thank Bjarne, but when I did this, only return the first value of Value1.

Comment: oh, sorry, did not read your code properly, I've done some edits, this will append the responses to a array before returning it

Comment: So, how can used my "value1" data like a generator, because of I search and all function use "radon data "

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def data():

    all_data = []
    value1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    for number,value in enumerate(value1):
        data = [time() * 1000, value]
        all_data.append(data)

    response = make_response(json.dumps(all_data))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'

    return response
```